# vuejs pass data-* attribut + text

Tags: vue.js, attributes

I need pass in data-title text "Get presentation [name]"

Works: `<a href="#popup-form" class="plan-btn" :data-title="hous.text">Get</a>`
However I need as well pass "Get presentation"

Does not work: `<a href="#popup-form" class="plan-btn" :data-title="Get presentation hous.text">Get</a>`

Comment: Use a computed property to generate 'Get presentation' + name, eventually you can also get 'Get presentation'  from a translation file.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js all data bindings (like your `:data-title`) support JavaScript expressions. As in plain JavaScript you can concat strings with the "+" Operator; like that:

```
<a href="#popup-form" class="plan-btn" :data-title="'Get presentation ' + hous.text">Get</a>
```

However, it is advisable to use a computed property in such a case:

```
<template>
  <a href="#popup-form" class="plan-btn" :data-title="dataTitle">Get</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        dataTitle() {
            return 'Get presentation ' + this.hous.text;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```